# Typescript string date format in chronological order

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to sort the string dates to chronological order, experts inputs please?

Let say have an array object like

```
data = [
{id: "1", date: "18.08.2018"}
{id: "2", date: "05.01.2014"}
{id: "3", date: "01.01.2014"}
{id: "4", date: "20.05.2016"}
]
```

**Expected is ,**
when I click on the button, data should return chronological order like

```
 data = [
           {id: "3", date: "01.01.2014"}
           {id: "2", date: "05.01.2014"}
           {id: "4", date: "20.05.2016"}
           {id: "1", date: "18.08.2018"}  

    ]
```

I tried this, but it is sorting only based dates and months but **not considering the year**

```
data.sort(function(a,b){return b.date - a.date});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort each by converting them into date and comparing them:

```js
let data = [{
    id: "1",
    date: "18.08.2018"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    date: "05.01.2014"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    date: "01.01.2014"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    date: "20.05.2016"
  },
]
//asc
console.log(data.sort((a, b) => {
  var d1 = a.date.split('.'),
    d2 = b.date.split('.');
  return new Date(d1[2], d1[1] - 1, d1[0]) - new Date(d2[2], d2[1] - 1, d2[0]);
  //--------------^Year--^Month-----^day
}));

//desc
console.log(data.sort((a, b) => {
  var d1 = a.date.split('.'),
    d2 = b.date.split('.');
  return new Date(d2[2], d2[1] - 1, d2[0]) - new Date(d1[2], d1[1] - 1, d1[0]);
}));
```

Comment: It is working fine in javascript but in typescript not working giving error like "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

Answer (score 0):

Using basic string compare

compare per char under ascii

---

data.sort(function(a,b){return b.date - a.date});

not work becuz

1. b.date-a.date

   is minus from day then month then year

   means "30-10-2010" - "19-10-2019" is bigger than 0

   '3'-'1' >0 return 1

   means "30-10-2010" - "31-10-2019" is smaller than 0

   '3'-'3' =0 return '0'>'1'     ---->return -1
2. a.date b.date is string using - not work in some times because somewhere not

   cast string to ascii will get Nan

```js
let data = [{
    id: "1",
    date: "18.08.2018"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    date: "05.01.2014"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    date: "01.01.2014"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    date: "20.05.2016"
  },
]
var Rs=data.sort((a, b) => {
  var d1 = a.date.split('.');
  var d2 = b.date.split('.');
  return (d1[2]+d1[1]+d1[0]).localeCompare(d2[2]+d2[1]+d2[0]);
});
//Using basic string compare
//compare per char under ascii
var S1="Apple";
var S2="Apzle";
var S3="Apzle";
var S4="Apzle ";
console.log(S1.localeCompare(S2));
console.log(S2.localeCompare(S1));
console.log(S3.localeCompare(S3));
console.log(S3.localeCompare(S4));

console.log(Rs);
```